# UIView Controller height less than than original Height swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My UIViewcontroller height is less than what is should be. I am getting UIView height as 729. It should be 812. I have added a textview with frame as UIScreen.main.bounds.height-(heightofTextView+10). But it is getting out of view and not clickable.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the storyboard with the constraints?

Comment: I am creating view programatically.

Comment: It seems like you are creating the textView and setting its frame before the parent view has been loaded so the frame of the parent view is not properly calculated yet. Either use constraints or set the frame of your textView after the parent view's frame is calculated

Comment: Without seeing your code, how do you expect anyone can help?

Comment: It is hard to answer if you do it through the code and we cant see it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing View Controller height from fixed to free form and then give your desired height